# Why doesn't removing event listeners work?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this in my constructor:

```
addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, actualDestroy);
```

And this in actualDestroy:

```
    public function actualDestroy(e:* = null){
        removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,actualDestroy);
        if(this.parent){
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }
```

The problem is I get Error: Error #2094: Event dispatch recursion overflow. Why does removechild keep getting called if this.parent does not exist? Why doesn't removing event listeners work?

Comment: I cannot understand, why are you trying to remove DisplayObject from stage after it has been already removed.

Comment: I call actualDestroy(null); somewhere else in the code. actualDestroy has more code than that.

Comment: Could it be that you are calling the removeEventListener regardless of whether the parent exists? i.e. move the removeEventListener inside the if statement.

Not seeing all your code it's difficult to say if this is the case but should you also be removing the eventListener from the item being destroyed? i.e. e.target.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,actualDestroy);

Comment: Nope, there is no removeEventListeners anywhere else. I don't like to duplicate code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the event is misleading. `removedFromStage`, according to the docs, is "dispatched when a display object is **about to be removed from the display list**". In other words, this is what's happening in your code:

1. Somewhere in your code, you call `parent.removeChild(this)`
2. `actualDestroy` is immediately called. At this point, **the object is still in the display list**, so `this.parent != null`
3. In `actualDestroy`, you call `parent.removeChild(this)` again.
4. Go to step 2

So to fix the issue, you might want to refactor your code (an object removing itself from the display list is never a good idea anyway), or perhaps use some boolean like `beingRemoved` to check whether the object is being removed from the list already. In which case, don't call `parent.removeChild(this)` in `actualDestroy`.