# Why is eventListener being removed after removing parent child

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

I have three different event listeners, one for opening a lightbox, one for closing lightbox, and one for adding a watch later feature.

So when after clicking the close button none of the eventListeners exist anymore. the basic code example:

```
var a ={
   open_lightbox:function(ele){
      ele.addEventListener('click',function(){
          //code that creates dynamic html and so forth.
      },false); 
    }, 
   close_lightbox:function(){
      var closer = a.get('.lightbox_close')[0];
      closer.addEventListener('click',function(){
        var p = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
      },false);
    },
   watch_later:function(ele){
        ele.addEventListener('click',function(){
           //uses localStorage to save data and then adds parameters
        },false);
    },
   get:function(ele){ return document.querySelectorAll(ele); }
 };

  var lightbox = a.get('.lightbox_button'),i;
  for(i=0;i<lightbox.length;i++){
     a.open_lightbox(lightbox[i]);
   }
```

Now when ever I click the main event `open_lightbox`, I can't reopen the lightbox nor click the watch_later element. All the original eventListeners are removed, is it because of the false `use capture`?  I haven't tried changing `false` to `true` though I will. I just need an explanation to why this is happening as this is my first time in years ever running into this issue.

Testing that replicates the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/ES5h2/

I did more testing and it's not on the click of the close button but after the first click of the element to open the lightbox.

Comment: If you can show us how the HTML looks like, then we won't need to read the crystal ball.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252211/why-doesnt-removing-event-listeners-work

Comment: This is true, I was thinking maybe it was just something silly in my javascript. I'll try to update with the html

Comment: I've updated the question with a link of what is going on.

Comment: I've tried your fiddle. When I click on the image, I can see the lightbox_close DIV added to the DOM, but I don't see it on the page. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah its on the far right. It could be some of my css that I quickly added instead of filling the fiddle with all my js and html.

Comment: Though frieder is giving a workaround for the issue at hand, I still would like to get an explanation to this result as I am not removing the eventListeners that should still exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why this was canceling the Event Listener on each event, though I did figure out a more semantic way. Which is just doing...

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      if(/lightbox_btn/gi.test(e.target.className)){
        //perform the code
      }
},false);
```

So really I just took it and added the event Listener to the document instead of the element itself. It works fine now

Answer (score 1):

i would try not to delete the element, but to hide it

you could use

`p.style.display = "none";`

instead of

`p.parentNode.removeChild(p);`

Comment: That is true, but then I would have to dynamically change all the content within the lightbox that needs to be changed. It needs to be sorted out correctly as there will be too much data that needs to be changed once this code gets further

Comment: Also I've been considering it, as it would lower the data load in the watch later list, for if they have 100 videos in the watch later it would need to load 100 images. Its just going to suck if I need to change all the data attributes and all the other content that will need to be changed. Though then again it may be the best option as the watch later list will have the same concept needing to change everything. So up vote for you if I decide to hide I will mark yours as correct

Comment: then you could use `replaceChild()` instead of `appendChild()` while you create the p element and the elements simply will be changed

Comment: This is true, I need to work on some of this, as the display none part is not the best suitable as the video keeps playing. And I am not using the YT API as to keep this as small as possible.

Comment: Ok so the issue at hand is that the actual event handlers are disappearing after the first click not on click of the closer

Comment: it would be great to know the code which causes this, in your eventlistener function

Comment: I've told you. The open _ lightbox function